# Aggregate per timestamp datapoints in graphite

Tags: graphite, statsd

My first post so be gentle please! So I have an installation of graphite up and running on Ubuntu 16.04 server. (version 0.10)

I am sending in metrics and everything works fine, but I am sending in multiple timestamps at once. As in I am sending in data once per minute with per 10s timestamps. Every minute new data comes in. It can happen, that a key with a corresponding timestamp (same as before) is resent a minute later. So the new value is being saved and last one lost, because of the way graphite works. So I put a carbon-aggregator in front of carbon-cache thinking it will aggregate the values per timestamp. It does not. It aggregates all values received in a time interval ignoring the timestamps.

I found that statsd has the same functionality. What I want is for the aggregator to aggregate values per timestamp. As in keep data for lets say 1 minute and see if a datapoint for the same key and timestamp is received. If so sum them. If no such data came, forward the original data to carbon-cache.

Is there a way to do this with graphite or statsd, or do I have to write my own little buffer in front of carbon-cache (instead of carbon-aggregator), that does this? It could be a linked list of self made structures in C resulting in about 150 lines of code, but would take precious time.

Someone has definitely had the same problem, but has anyone found a solution?

Bump: has noone really encountered this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) might be one solution.

It can receive/understand carbon metrics (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-graphite.html), and can be made to generate metrics, which seems to do everything *except* the summing you mention (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-metrics.html). It can also re-emit the metrics in a format graphite will understand (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-graphite.html).

You may also be able to do something clever with the aggregate plugin (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html).

It does sound, though, like if you were able to do something about the way the stats/metrics are being generated in the first place, it might be an easier way to address the issue.

Comment: Changing the way stats are generated is not quite an option since it is done by a 3rd party software. I will look into logstash. Thank you! Will mark the answer as solution if no other appears in a couple of days.

Comment: It appears, the `metrics`-plugin aggregates per period of _log processing_ -- rather than per the period of the aggregated events _occuring_. That is, if I "replay" the last week's log, the events recorded in it will be processed as if occurring at the time of replaying...